# Magento 2 search not working

Tags: magento2

If I type in the search box as HP then the search results not showing. I have products already as HP laptops and accessories. Can you guys help me, please?

Comment: please check store configuration for catalog search "minimal query length"   store-> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> catalog search -> minimal query length - 2